# CreateRecording fails with "The RecordConfiguration is invalid" for Onvif Profile G device

Tags: soap, onvif

I am trying to createRecording on Profile G device;

The request body is as below:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<recording:CreateRecording>
<recording:RecordingConfiguration xsi:type="onv:RecordingConfiguration">
<onv:Source xsi:type="onv:RecordingSourceInformation">
<onv:SourceId>http://10.65.158.165/onvif/recording_service</onv:SourceId>
<onv:Name>BSONIRecName</onv:Name>
<onv:Location>BSONIRecLocation</onv:Location>
<onvescription>BSONIRecDescription</onvescription>
<onv:Address>http://10.65.158.165/onvif/recording_service</onv:Address>
</onv:Source>
<onv:Content>BSONIRecContent</onv:Content>
<onv:MaximumRetentionTime>100</onv:MaximumRetentionTime>
</recording:RecordingConfiguration>
</recording:CreateRecording>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

But, I am always getting error saying

```
<env:Code>
<env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
<env:Subcode>
<env:Value>ter:InvalidArgVal</env:Value>
<env:Subcode>
<env:Value>ter:BadConfiguration</env:Value>
</env:Subcode>
</env:Subcode>
</env:Code>
<env:Reason>
<env:Text xml:lang="en">The RecordConfiguration is invalid.</env:Text>
</env:Reason>
```

Can anybody see, whats wrong in the request format.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a type mismatch at MaximumRetentionTime which is xs:duration type, not a simple number string.

So changing this param to "P7D" solves the problem.